# Splitting emails for a single domain into two

Tags: email, postfix

I have a situation, where i have about 20,000 emails hosted on a server with domain mydomain.com. Out of those 20,000, there are 20 email accounts, for which i want my MX servers, to route their emails to another Postfix server, which is is latest and updated. Reason for doing this is that i have same domain name , for all of 20,000 email address. i want to keep the domain name same, but route emails of 20 unique email address to another server.

Is that possible? if yes how?
May be i have to use postfix transport tables on MX servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use transport maps

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

/etc/postfix/transport
uniq_mail1@mydomain.com smtp:[remote.postfix.ip.address]
uniq_mail2@mydomain.com smtp:[remote.postfix.ip.address]
uniq_mail3@mydomain.com smtp:[remote.postfix.ip.address]
...
uniq_mail20@mydomain.com smtp:[remote.postfix.ip.address]
```

Don't forget to create map file and restart the postfix

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/transport
# service postfix restart
```

Comment: is it possible that i can save a copy of email to source server and send that email to other server as well?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can use separate email address/virtual_alias_maps or use something like procmail