# Change mail headers and send back to Office 365 using Postfix

Tags: postfix

I have a outbound and inbound connector setup on my Office365. Outbound connector is sending all emails from my users to Postfix which is on premises. I do some processing with Postfix and then I send this same email back to Office 365 without ever changing the From or To addresses.

It is possible my users can send to any domain so my Postfix should accept emails for any domain as long as it's coming from Office365.

Is it possible that I can receive email for example.com and save it in a Maildir folder, then make some changes to headers and send it to another SMTP server from the same Postfix instance?

Problem I have right now is that once Postfix is configured to accept email for a domain. I can't find a way to also send the emails destined for a user in that domain to another SMTP server. I have achieved it from the Python script but I want to see if I can achieve it using Postfix.

Comment: You could use relayhost, and not mess with the headers at all (messing with headers, even if possible, sounds like a very bad idea). But I don't know if you're trying to use this particular server to be the final destination for some people on the domain.... Google Postfix Split Domain Routing. I've never done it before, but I know it can be done.... https://serverfault.com/questions/575296/splitting-emails-for-a-single-domain-into-two

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am adding another Key/Value to header. Also, I receive email let's say for abc@abc.com. I then give it to a Python script that adds a header and tries to send that same email (still the recipient stays the same abc@abc.com) to another SMTP server. But my Postfix complains that there is a loop and bounces the email message.

Comment: @David W: "messing with headers" can be a very good idea if you use OpenDKIM or SpamAssassin.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I admittedly am not an expert in this stuff. Unrelated: I think your response should be posted as a comment, and not as an answer.

Comment: yes I should, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to pass the mail to an external script. You can make an alias which delivers to a local mailbox and pipes to a script using something like:

```
someuser: \someuser, "|/usr/local/sbin/relayscript.py"
```

in `/etc/aliases`. You will need to have alias processing enabled in `main.cf` with:

```
alias_maps=hash:/etc/aliases
```

Comment: Hmm, from your comment above it looks like you're trying to send to the same address? Your script should handle rewriting the 'To:' address to send to wherever you need the modified email to go, and then make its own SMTP connection. If you're using Python then https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html might give you some pointers on how to handle that.

Comment: Thank you James. I have achieved it form the Python script but i want to see if I can achieve it using Postfix. Here is the complete scenario. I have a outbound and inbound connector setup on my Office365. Outbound connector is sending all emails from my users to Postfix which is on premises. I do some processing with postfix and then i send this same email back to office 365 without ever changing the From or To addresses.  It is possible my users can send to any domain so my postfix should accept emails for any domain as long as coming from Office365.

Comment: Continued from previous comment: All these emails end up in the same folder. When email arrives a python script is triggered which adds another Header then tries to send the same email back to Office 365 to it can be sent to the actual destined recipient.

Comment: Presumably you don't have the relevant domains in `$mydestination` if it's any domain, so Postfix is acting as a relay? If that's the case you might be able to inject your header with `header_checks` (there's an example here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44123/add-header-to-outgoing-email-with-postfix) and then use a `relayhost` setting to pass the mail to Office365 again. I presume there's some mechanism that stops Office365 just sending it back to you?

Comment: The mechanism is the header. So O365 is only sending emails to my Postfix if it doesn't have the header so to not create a loop. I am also doing some other stuff with emails thus can't use the header_checks the email has to pass to a script.

Comment: Sounds like using the script to pass it back is probably the sane solution if it's already in the mix. The other possibility I can think of is setting up a second SMTP instance in your `master.cf` on another port with different configuration and having your script pass the mail to that. I suspect that will be ugly and complicated, though.

Comment: Based on the comments, you were asking something totally different from your original post. I tried to help you to ask the right things by adding the details from these comments.

Comment: Thanks Esa. I am still waiting to see if someone knows how to achieve it using Postfix or if it is even possible.